# Selecting nested subexpressions in a Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As a part of a GUI design that I'm implementing in Java swing, I need the user to be able to select parts or subparts of a tree like structure represented as a string.

For example, if I were to display the following expression, `((a|b)|(c|d))`

The user would need to be able to select any of the following
`(a|b)`, `(c|d)` or the entire thing `((a|b)|(c|d))`.

Ideally I'd like them to be able to navigate via the keyboard arrows, moving up and down though the nested subexpressions, and hit enter when they come to the subexpression they want. However if its only possible to do this on mouse click, thats also acceptable.

The main issue that I'm having with this is the nesting component. I could easily make the entire expression selectable, but I don't know how to allow subexpressions to be selectable using SWING components. Based on my research Swing doesn't allow nesting of labels of text areas in the manner that I need so I'm looking for any alternatives.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding working with raw strings, and instead use a tree-based model for your data.  Then you can use a treeview to display it.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Comment: Well the data is stored in a custom object much like a tree, it just needs to appear to the user as a string (I've edited the question to be clearer). The treeview looks promising as long as I can customise the appearance to be horizontal rather than vertical.

Comment: You can make a read-only JTextField, capturing keys and mouse clicks, handle the arrow keys, and highlight "(...)" using HTML text "<html>((a|b)...".

Comment: @JoopEggen I was thinking about html too, but how can I let the application know that a subexpression was selected and which one it was?

Comment: @fredo answered it nicely. The user navigates his text selection (with caret on `(`) with arrow keys or mouse click. This you achieve with listeners. On pressing Enter or double click the text selection (sub-expression) is passed. As swing text selection on read-only JTextField might not be visible, you can change the text introducing a `<span style='color: #ffff33'>` (or set document attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Highlighter` and a `DocumentListener` on the read-only `JTextField` suggested by Joop in the comment above, following http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html in the section about `JTextFieldDemo`. That way you can highlight your (partial) string and listen to what (sub)string is selected, and compare it to the original string to check for matches.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I'll give it a try over the weekend and wait for other answers before I mark yours as accepted though. Thank you